# How to get value from JSON response from array of dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

unable to get Array of dictionary value

this is my model

```
public var featured_product : Array<Featured_product>?

    public class Featured_product {
    public var wishlist : wishlist?
    }

     required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
       if (dictionary["wishlist"] != nil) { wishlist = Aswagna.wishlist(dictionary: dictionary["wishlist"] as? NSDictionary ?? NSDictionary())}
   }

public class wishlist {
public var id : Int?
}
```

here i want `wishlist-> id`.. for that i have tried like below

```
@IBAction func addToWishList(_ sender: UIButton){
 
    if let data = self.homDB?.result?.product?.featured_product{

        for wishlistData in data.wishlist ?? []{

            idFav = wishlistData["id"]
        }
    }
    
}
```

**error** in for loop `data.wishlist`

> Value of type '[Featured_product]' has no member 'wishlist'

how do i get `wishlist id`.. please do help

**Edit**: `addToWishList` is the collectionview cell button action.. i have given its action to `HomeVC` from storyboard cell

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController{
var homDB = HomeDataModel(dictionary: NSDictionary())
@IBAction func addToWishList(_ sender: UIButton){
 //here i need selected button's wishlist id
  
  idFav = self.homDB?.result?.product?.featured_product?[sender.tag].wishlist?.id
  print("wishlist id \(idFav)")
 }

}
```

if i do like above then `print("wishlist id \(idFav)")` getting nil.. where am i wrong.. pls do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is straightforward. The error message states that`data` is an array of `Featured_product` and that the array has no member `wishlist`. You need to access the individual array element before accessing `wishlist`:

```
    for wishlistData in data ?? []{

        idFav = wishlistData["wishlist"].id
    }
```

Regarding the second one, I would suggest to unwrap each element of your chain one at  time to get a better understanding of which one is nil.